# SSIS cast to DT_WSTR not casting, or so it seems

Tags: casting, ssis

I'm creating an SSIS 2008 package that reads data from an ASCII flat file source and writes it to a SQL Server 2008 database. BIDS was complaining about the implicit cast between unicode and non-unicode data types, so I used a derived column tool to make the cast. This is what it looks like:

```
Derived Column Name  |  Derived Column  |  Expression          |  Data Type
AccountName2         |  Replace 'AName' | (DT_WSTR,100) AName  |  string [DT_STR]
```

I'm still getting the same error:

```
Validation error. InsertAccountRecords: InsertAccountRecords: Columns "AccountName2" and "AName" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.
```

The error is showing up in the SQL Server Destination, which leads me to believe the problem is the Data Type in the derived column. I'm casting it from DT_STR to DT_WSTR, but the Data Type is still nominally DT_STR according to this, no?

I've Googled around, and I can't seem to find any good answers to this question. Can anyone provide any guidance?

Edit: Yup. Looking at the Data Viewer downstream of the Derived Columns, AccountName2 is still coming up as DT_STR. Why isn't the cast casting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190169.aspx) notes that the new data type is set correctly only when you choose to add a new column. You need to select "add as new column" in the Derived Column drop-down.

Or just use the Data Conversion transformation, which is probably easier if changing the data type is the only transformation you're making.

Comment: Yep. That was 100% the case, and adding the Data Converstion transformation made things much simpler.

Comment: Still, I have to wonder, why, why, why !?
Why should they choose NOT to set the data type correctly on replace...?

Comment: @igorludi I don't know, but SSIS is very conservative about handling data types, e.g. implicit conversion is not allowed. So my guess would be that the design decision was made that a single column can't have different data types at different places in the package. That would avoid problems with packages suddenly breaking because someone adds a new data type transformation and doesn't update the 'downstream' logic: by using a new column, you have to update the whole package. And it might make some metadata operations like lineage analysis easier. But I have no evidence for this guess.

Comment: OK, seems reasonable enough.
One thing thoough, I'm not so sure about implicit conversions.
For instance, I have setup two data flows, using:
AdoNet->AdoNet
OledDb->OleDb
using the same databases (and tables) for src and dest.
Former automatically converts non-unicode to unicode string, and latter results in an error (and that is how I came here :)).